# Number system for operation

Tags: number-systems

The last digit of some number  in base  is 2. Last number of $12_{10}*X$ in the same system is 4. How many systems that are suitable for these conditions for any X.

I m really confused for example I take $3_{10}$ as X, so for any system last digit will be 3, so there are no such systems?

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence.  Did you mean to say, "The last *digit* of some *number* $X$ in base $k$ is $2?$"

Comment: Correct, I'll edit that...

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.  What they are asking is, for what values of $k$ is it true that if the last digit of a number $X$ in base $k$ is $2,$ then the last last digit of of $12_{10}X$ in base $k$ is $4.$  For example, this is true if $k=10.$

Comment: It seems like you are right... but how can I determine all such systems?

Comment: And to be sure that it's correct for all digits, for example k = 10:
2, 12*2 = 24
how can i be sure that for ...2, 12*...2 = ....4

Comment: It feels like I m missing something really simple, but I can't understand what exactly I should be looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get you started.  First of all, we must have $k>4$ or we couldn't have the digit $4$.  Then the last digit of $X$ in base $k$ is $2$ if and only if $$X\equiv2\pmod{k}$$  Then we know that $$12X\equiv24\pmod{k}$$
and we need $$12X\equiv4\pmod{k}$$ in order for the last digit to be $4$.

So the question becomes, for what values of $k>4$ is it true that $$Y\equiv24\pmod{k}\implies Y\equiv4\pmod{k}$$

Well, if $k|(-4)$ and $k|(Y-24)$ then $k$ divides their difference, so $k|20$.  The admissible $k$ are $5,10,20$.

Comment: I understand that and feeling guilty that I can't make further conclusions...

Comment: Big thanks!!!!!!

Comment: @Hmmman It was my pleasure.